# How to sort a sub value of a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, multidimensional-array

I have a variable when var_dump it output this value

> string(86) "[new Date(2011, 07, 10), 10],[new Date(2011, 07, 19), 50],[new Date(2011, 07, 18), 61]"

I need to sort the string value based on the date value 
I mean

```
    new Date(2011, 07, 10)
    new Date(2011, 07, 18)
    new Date(2011, 07, 19)
```

how to do this?.

Comment: So you want to sort the items in the string to be in chronological order? Parse the string items into an array sort the array and create a string from that sorted array.

Comment: where is the values from? is the possibility to get values before they come to string? may be better when you wil sort before generate string?

Comment: hello sub digger                                                    foreach ($ga->getResults() as $result) { 
    $date = explode(' ', $result);
    $visits = $result->getVisits();
    $j_input .= "[new Date($date[0], $date[1], $date[2]),$visits],";
    $output = substr($j_input, 0, -1);
The value of the output is now displayed, i need to sort the string according to $date[2]. 
}

Comment: @Ezhil: Make it an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
function sort_date($a, $b)
{
    return $a[2] > $b[2] ? -1 : ($b[2] > $a[2] ? 1 : 0);
}

$date_list = array();
foreach ($ga->getResults() as $result) {
 $date = explode(' ', $result);
 $date[] = $result->getVisits();
 $date_list[] = $date;
} 

usort($date_list, 'sort_date');

$j_input = '';
foreach ($date_list as $date)
  $j_input .= "[new Date(".$date[0].", ".$date[1].", ".$date[2]."),".$date[3]."],";
```

or may be if $ga is your object then this ability better to place into object

Comment: man you are perfectly righty , got stuck with this for hours and you breaked it in seconds. thank you so much.